# Conda env corrupted

Tags: anaconda, conda

Checked the conda environment using the below command:

```
 > conda info


ERROR: The install method you used for conda--probably either `pip install conda`
or `easy_install conda`--is not compatible with using conda as an application.
If your intention is to install conda as a standalone application, currently
supported install methods include the Anaconda installer and the miniconda
installer.  You can download the miniconda installer from 
https://conda.io/miniconda.html.
```

Comment: How did you install `conda`?

Answer (score 0):

If you had a working version of a conda environment before this error started to occur, you can revert back to that working environment using this command:

```
conda list --revision
```

and

```
conda install --revision [n]
```

Otherwise, you can try to [re]install conda from the miniconda [install](https://conda.io/miniconda.html) web page: